# Conditional initialization of global variable in C

Tags: c, macros

I want to do conditional initialization in global matrix; is it possible as below (pseudo code)? Please suggest some alternative.

```
char a[][] = {{1,2,3,4},
#ifdef init
              {1,3,4,5}, // I want to make this conditional
#endif
              {1,4,5,6}
             }

main ()
{
    #define init 1;
}
```

Comment: `#define init 1;` suggests that you do not really understand the difference between the preprocessor and the compiler, which is a fundamental concept with regards to the question at hand.

Comment: I know above is wrong, I was just trying to explain what I want to do..it is hard to explain otherwise, please don't be that picky

Comment: It's not about being picky, I just had a feeling that you were trying to solve a problem in the wrong way.

Comment: your feeling is right, my feeling is also the same..that is why I dared to post this question

Comment: For preprocessor definitions to span across multiple lines, you need to add a backslash (\\) at the end of every line **except** for the last line. Other than that, your code should compile successfully. But you still need to decide what to do with that `init` definition, because it is certainly not located where it should typically be (on the "global scope"), the semicolon (`;`) is redundant, and as a matter of fact, so is the `1`, as you are checking `#ifdef init`.

Comment: Do you expect to decide this at runtime, or at compile time? Also, do you really have different matrix dimensions depending on which is chosen? How do you intend to know the currently chosen size?

Comment: In short, it's hard to say what your example is *supposed* to do, so it's hard to give any kind of alternative.

Comment: This is the actual problem, as the marco will be expanded at prepossessing time, so there is actually no way to manipulate the globally initialized matrix at run time, rather than replacing it completely with new values at run time..this thing s**ks

Comment: @codeymodey Of course there are ways. If you have several matrixes and want to switch between them, use a pointer and set it to point to the right matrix (you may also need extra variables telling current matrixes size, in which case you might want to wrap the whole thing in a `struct`). Or you can have the "current" matrix as copy, and copy the right one over it as needed (again using structs may make things easier, and note that you can assign structs even if they contain arrays, as long as it's same struct type).

Comment: Yes, sir I got it. I mean it is not possible sticking to above scenario, anyways I resolved the problem in some other way. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `a` a global pointer and then initialize conditionally using malloc.

```
char **a;

int main()
{
    if (condition){
        a = malloc(some_size);
        //initialize the memory here
    }
    else {
        a = malloc(other_size);
        //or initialize differently here 
    }
```

}